# Hibernate NullPointerException on Entity field set (UPDATE)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a problem with Hibernate 4.3.0Final that I have been unable to solve.  It is puzzling because I am running similar code in several other places which is working fine.  The below code is throwing a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.  It is running in a web service in using a NetBeans setup using Glassfish and JavaDB.

The exception is thrown after `item.setRoomId(-1);`:
`characterId`, `characterFirstName`, `roomId`, k, variables are being passed in from above; I have verified via debugging that they all have values with valid datatypes; also a valid record is in the Items table.

```
Query itemsQuery = em.createNamedQuery("Items.findByRoomIdByName");
itemsQuery.setParameter("roomId", roomId);
itemsQuery.setParameter("name", itemName);
Items item = null;
if (itemsQuery.getResultList().isEmpty()) {
    throw new UnableToIdentifyException("Item does not exist!  You cannot get an item that does not exist.  Did you already pick it up?");
}
else {
    item = (Items) itemsQuery.getSingleResult();
    Boolean isStuck = item.getIsUnmovable();
    if (isStuck) {
        //Item stuck
        notifyItemGetViewers(characterId, characterFirstName, roomId, itemName, isStuck);
    }
    else {
        //Pick up item
        try {
            item.setRoomId(-1);
            item.setCharacterId(characterId);
            item.setStoreId(-1);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.severe("Wrapped Exection Caught: Exception: " + e.toString() + " Error Message: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        em.persist(item);
        em.flush();

        notifyItemGetViewers(characterId, characterFirstName, roomId, itemName, isStuck);
    }
}
```

### Entity class (Items.java)

```
package org.tav.mit;

import java.beans.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "mit_items")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="Items.findByItemId",
                query="SELECT i FROM Items i WHERE i.itemId = :itemId"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Items.findByRoomIdByName",
                query="SELECT i FROM Items i WHERE i.roomId = :roomId AND i.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Items.findByRoomId",
                query="SELECT i FROM Items i WHERE i.roomId = :roomId"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Items.findByCharacterId",
                query="SELECT i FROM Items i WHERE i.characterId = :characterId"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Items.findByStoreId",
                query="SELECT i FROM Items i WHERE i.storeId = :storeId"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Items.findByName",
                query="SELECT i FROM Items i WHERE i.name = :name")
})
public class Items implements Serializable {
    public static final String PROP_ITEMID = "itemIdProperty";
    public static final String PROP_ROOMID = "roomIdProperty";
    public static final String PROP_CHARACTERID = "characterIdProperty";
    public static final String PROP_STOREID = "storeIdProperty";
    public static final String PROP_NAME = "nameProperty";
    public static final String PROP_DESCRIPTION = "descriptionProperty";
    public static final String PROP_TYPE = "typeProperty";
    public static final String PROP_WORTH = "worthProperty";
    public static final String PROP_BODYLOCATION = "bodyLocationProperty";
    public static final String PROP_ISUNMOVABLE = "isUnmovableProperty";
    public static final String PROP_ACBONUS = "acBonusProperty";
    public static final String PROP_USETIMEDELAY = "useTimeDelayProperty";
    public static final String PROP_DAMAGEDICE = "damageDiceProperty";
    public static final String PROP_DAMAGEDICESIDES = "damageDiceSidesProperty";
    public static final String PROP_DAMAGETYPE = "damageTypeProperty";
    public static final String PROP_LIGHTPROVIDED = "lightProvidedProperty";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer itemId;
    @Column()
    private Integer roomId = -1;
    @Column()
    private Integer characterId = -1;
    @Column()
    private Integer storeId = -1;
    @Column(length = 128, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(length = 2048, nullable = true)
    private String description;
    @Column()
    private Integer type = -1;
    @Column()
    private Double worth = 0.0;
    @Column()
    private Integer bodyLocation = -1;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean isUnmovable = false;
    @Column()
    private Integer acBonus = -1;
    @Column()
    private Integer useTimeDelay = -1;
    @Column()
    private Integer damageDice = -1;
    @Column()
    private Integer damageDiceSides = -1;
    @Column()
    private Integer damageType = -1;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean lightProvided = false;
    @Column(length = 2048)
    private PropertyChangeSupport propertySupport;

    public Items()
    {
        propertySupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public int getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }
    public void setItemId(Integer itemId) {
        Integer oldValue = this.itemId;
        this.itemId = itemId;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_ITEMID, oldValue, itemId);
    }

    public int getRoomId() {
        return roomId;
    }
    public void setRoomId(Integer roomId) {
        Integer oldValue = this.roomId;
        this.roomId = roomId;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_ROOMID, oldValue, roomId);
    }

    public int getCharacterId() {
        return characterId;
    }
    public void setCharacterId(Integer characterId) {
        Integer oldValue = this.characterId;
        this.characterId = characterId;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_CHARACTERID, oldValue, characterId);
    }

    public int getStoreId() {
        return storeId;
    }
    public void setStoreId(Integer storeId) {
        Integer oldValue = this.storeId;
        this.storeId = storeId;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_STOREID, oldValue, storeId);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        String oldValue = this.name;
        this.name = name;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_NAME, oldValue, name);
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        String oldValue = this.description;
        this.description = description;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_DESCRIPTION, oldValue, description);
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(Integer type) {
        Integer oldValue = this.type;
        this.type = type;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_TYPE, oldValue, type);
    }

    public double getWorth() {
        return worth;
    }
    public void setWorth(double worth) {
        double oldValue = this.worth;
        this.worth = worth;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_WORTH, oldValue, worth);
    }

    public int getBodyLocation() {
        return bodyLocation;
    }
    public void setBodyLocation(Integer bodyLocation) {
        Integer oldValue = this.bodyLocation;
        this.bodyLocation = bodyLocation;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_BODYLOCATION, oldValue, bodyLocation);
    }

    public boolean getIsUnmovable() {
        return isUnmovable;
    }
    public void setIsUnmovable(boolean isUnmovable) {
        boolean oldValue = this.isUnmovable;
        this.isUnmovable = isUnmovable;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_ISUNMOVABLE, oldValue, isUnmovable);
    }

    public int getAcBonus() {
        return acBonus;
    }
    public void setAcBonus(Integer acBonus) {
        Integer oldValue = this.acBonus;
        this.acBonus = acBonus;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_ACBONUS, oldValue, acBonus);
    }

    public int getUseTimeDelay() {
        return useTimeDelay;
    }
    public void setUseTimeDelay(Integer useTimeDelay) {
        Integer oldValue = this.useTimeDelay;
        this.useTimeDelay = useTimeDelay;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_USETIMEDELAY, oldValue, useTimeDelay);
    }

    public int getDamageDice() {
        return damageDice;
    }
    public void setDamageDice(Integer damageDice) {
        Integer oldValue = this.damageDice;
        this.damageDice = damageDice;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_DAMAGEDICE, oldValue, damageDice);
    }

    public int getDamageDiceSides() {
        return damageDiceSides;
    }
    public void setDamageDiceSides(Integer damageDiceSides) {
        Integer oldValue = this.damageDiceSides;
        this.damageDiceSides = damageDiceSides;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_DAMAGEDICESIDES, oldValue, damageDiceSides);
    }

    public int getDamageType() {
        return damageType;
    }
    public void setDamageType(Integer damageType) {
        Integer oldValue = this.damageType;
        this.damageType = damageType;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_DAMAGETYPE, oldValue, damageType);
    }

    public boolean getLightProvided() {
        return lightProvided;
    }
    public void setLightProvided(boolean lightProvided) {
        boolean oldValue = this.lightProvided;
        this.lightProvided = lightProvided;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_LIGHTPROVIDED, oldValue, lightProvided);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (itemId != -1 ? itemId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Items)) {
            return false;
        }
        Items other = (Items) object;
        if ((this.itemId == -1 && other.itemId != -1) || (this.itemId != -1 && 
                !((this.itemId) == (other.itemId)))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

THE DATA THAT IS IN THE ITEMS TABLE:
INSERT INTO mit_items (roomid, characterid, storeid, name, description, type, worth, bodylocation, isunmovable, acbonus, useTimeDelay, damageDice, damageDiceSides, damageType, lightprovided) VALUES(1, -1, -1, 'sword', 'plain steel sword', -1, 0.0, -1, false, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, false);

One interesting thing is that after the exception throws the database shows that the `roomId` has in fact been set to `-1`.  However the other fields have not been updated.  If I reorder the `setFields(-1)` methods the exception still trigger on the first method.  Also, originally the try-catch block was not there.  I had to add it in order to see the root cause exception because this method has the `@Transactional` annotation which wraps the exception in a general `RollbackException` that does not show the root cause exception.

Comment: You are catching `Exception` and then code still runs, are you getting any exception?

Comment: full stacktrace please

Comment: Wild guess is `propertySupport` is null

Comment: The root cause is a NullPointerException.  Full stacktrace is useless because the @Transactional annotation wraps in its own RollbackException, nonetheless the statement that causes the exception is the first one in the try { block, even if I reorder and put setStoreId(-1) up top it still throws it there, the same for setCharacterId().  You might be right about propertySupport being null but that would be a bug in Hibernate4.3.0Final, I am not sure how to debug something like that.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your `setXXX` check `propertySupport` value then you will know for sure. Also note that `propertySupport` cannot be a column and something you instantiate in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, RC that fixed the problem.  propertySupport was returning null.  Not sure why, it normally has a Long number in there, might be a bug in Hibernate as it works in other parts of my code. I don't really need the support I just though it would be a nice pattern to have.  I ended up removing propertySupport from Items.java Entity class which fixed the problem.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, RC that fixed the problem. propertySupport was returning null. Not sure why, it normally has a Long number cast to a String in there. I ended up removing propertySupport from Items.java Entity class which fixed the problem.

I have feeling why it was failing in this case and not others is because I was manually inserting a record in the Items table for testing and I left the propertySupport field null.  So apparently if you have propertySupport implemented you cannot update values in a record that has a null propertySupport field, which I guess would only occur if you inserted the data by a means other than the entity bean.

Thanks again RC! – Sam